# How do I handle Threads in Xamarin apps?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to use the `NetworkDiscovery` in my Xamarin app and convert all the needed classes from [Android's NsdChat application](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) to C#.

I'm calling the Android code via `DependencyService` and it looks like the UI freezes right after I start a `Thread`.

For example:

```
public GameClient(InetAddress inetAddress, int port)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Creating chatClient");
        InetAddress = inetAddress;
        PORT = port;
        SendThread = new Thread(new SendingThread(inetAddress,port));
        SendThread.Start(); //the UI begins to freeze here
    }
```

I've read about making everything async, but this doesn't work here because the return type from Android to Xamarin PCL is different. On top of that I don't get any error messages from the debugger, other than a cryptic:

> No compatible code running

Comment: Are you interacting with any UI element in the code executing in the new thread?

Comment: You don't have to. Learn what is `async`/`await`.